# Protocol analysis for flash app

Tags: proxy, flash, reverse-engineering

Need analyze (reverse engineering} one flash application protocol. My idea is setup some proxy server, and capture all comminication thru.

What proxy server can do this job?

Or, is here better solution?

I can use Linux, freebsd or Macosx.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to capture the data on the network is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: And Wireshark is available for each of the listed platforms.